# Vagrant Multiple Machines Inter-SSH Key Authentication

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, coreos

I'm trying to setup a small virtual cluster with Vagrant, there is one Ubuntu machine and a few CoreOS machines. The problem I'm having is I need to setup key authentication ***between* the guest machines**.

I tried placing a private key to `.ssh/id_rsa` file and the public key into the `.ssh/authorized_keys` and played around with the `config.ssh.private_key_path` but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Is there some easy way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The problem I was having was that I was setting my own key, but Vagrant boxes come installed with [these keys](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/keys) and can't connect if you set `config.ssh.private_key_path` to a custom key. Found the hint in the documentation [here](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html), which I think could warn the user that they won't be able to connect if they tried to override the key while using a public box :

> `config.ssh.private_key_path` - The path to the private key to use to SSH into the guest machine. By default this is the insecure private key that ships with Vagrant, **since that is what public boxes use.** If you make your own custom box with a custom SSH key, this should point to that private key.

So the trick is that you should use Vagrant's provided keys, placing them in the appropriate `.ssh/id_rsa` and `.ssh/authorized_keys` slots.

Comment: How do you place those keys in upon vagrant up? Can you share your `Vagrantfile` perhaps?